# Unable to connect to socket - Vanilla JS to node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to work with socket.io, however I am unable to establish a connection between my client (Vanilla HTML/JS) and my server (node.js).

Server code:

```
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

var server = app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Listening on port 3001!'));
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("A user connected");
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log("user disconnected")
    })
})
```

I also have several endpoints and functions that are exposed in the same file, though they didn't seem relevant (as far as I know), so I didn't include them here, but can if needed.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

index.js:

```
window.onload = () => {
    var socket = io("http://localhost:3001")
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log("Connected")
        console.log(socket.connected)
    })
    socket.on('test', () => {
        console.log("In test socket on")
    })
}
```

I don't seem to be getting any errors thrown in the console or anything, and am not sure where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, the configuration I had for both the client and the server were ok, however it seems as though the issue was with the version of `socket.io` that I was using. The version I was using was `3.0.3`, however when rolling it back to `1.7.4`, the setup had worked and I was able to successfully connect to the socket. This isn't an ideal situation by any means, I believe with version 3, the configuration has to be modified. As a quick, temporary fix, this may help, though of course this is by no means an ideal, production-level solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by specifying the origin on cors. Don't just allow all origins through the cors. Instead of `app.use(cors())` , use `app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:8080', optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }))` or whatever your front end server port is. socket.io also has an option to set origin when initializing. Try this. `const io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately, neither of these seemed to work either. I also tried running my app on a cors-disabled chrome window, but I had the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And all i did was let Express know where my static files were.
With:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) //Make sure you set here you actual folder
```

(in my case it was "/public")

I'm using the CDN provided by Socket.io docs:

`<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`.

Also i'm declaring the CDN at the end of the file before the closing body tag before my actual JS script containing the implementation.

Also i'm using `res.sendFile(*insert here template path*)` for example `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/templates/index.html')`.